# Seach Column based on textbox value and display all results in Listbox

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I have a

```
ListBox = firmList; 
TextBox = firmGroupID; 
Worksheet = RelatedFirms; 
ColumnA = gID (ID numbers); 
ColumnB = firmName
```

I am trying to populate my list box based on the value of firmGroupID.
Currently I have a combobox that populates the gID number in firmGroupID depending on combobox selection.

I would then like the firmList to populate with the list of firmNames based on the firmGroupID.

Sheet RelatedFirms contains the assigned gID for each firmName.

This seems simple but everything I try doesn't seem to work.

Not sure how to only show items in list box that have the value that equals gID.

```
Private Sub firmGroupID_Change()
    Dim rngName As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("RelatedFirms")
    For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 1
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then Me.firmList.AddItem
        ws.Cells(i, 1).Value   
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? You need an `End If` line after `ws.Cells(i,1).Value`.  ...actually your If statement is written incorrectly.

Comment: Im sorry, I did not add the issue (im still new). No error it actually works fine, just not what I want.  It feels my listbox with everything instead of matching the value in firmGroupID with gID and only showing those results.

Answer (score 1):

Please change this code:

```
If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> vbNullString Then Me.firmList.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
```

To

```
If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = firmGroupID.Value Then Me.firmList.AddItem ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
```

Comment: No nothing is showing in the list box. Do I need to indicate gID anywhere? That is the name of the column in Worksheet(RelatedFirms) that firmGroupID needs to compare too.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help. I got it to work with this

Comment: I defined firmGroupID,  Dim s As String, s = firmGroupID.Value. Just one last question though.  How do I stop the loop so when I choose the next item it clears the listbox?  Thanks